# Why the ComboBox would add a top attribute on the table?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using a `combo-box` control inside `Grid View`.
I am trying to describe the problem clearly

My HTML Code:

```
<AJAX:ComboBox ID="ddlContactName1" runat="server" 
       AutoPostBack="true" Width="190px"
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlContactName_SelectIndexChanged"
       DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Enabled="false" CssClass="WindowsStyle"               AutoCompleteMode="Suggest">
</AJAX:ComboBox>
```

Code Generated by ASP on browser:

```
<td class="td_search_box">
 <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdContacts_ctl02_ddlContactType1" class="acb" style="display: inline-block;">
      <table id="ctl00_MainContent_grdContacts_ctl02_ddlContactType1_Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
     style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;
        display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 5px;">

...........
```

Combobox (ddlContactType1) renders as div and table inside. Table has class and style. Style has attribute "top: 5px;" causing padding from top.

As a result combobox is shifted on 5 pixels from top and lies above table grid line.

I want to make the `top:0px;`.How to do this?

Can anybody has any idea?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution.And hope it will help others,

```
<style type="text/css">
 .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer
    {
        top:0px !important;
    }

</style
```